Validating Username and Password in Keycloak
I am trying to validate a users username and password from keycloak backend because I have a custom authentication form. I was using the below code to validate the user, which is working as expected.
private UserModel getUserByUserNameAndPassword(AuthenticationFlowContext context, String username,
        String password) {
    RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();
    UserModel user = context.getSession().users().getUserByUsername(realm, username);
    if (user != null) {
        context.setUser(user);
        context.success();
    }
    return user;
}

But I cant validate the password of that user. Can somebody help me to use the password for validating the user.
Thanks in advance.

I might be completely wrong about this since I worked with Keycloak years ago, but I guess you're trying to use Keycloak in a way it doesn't make much sense. If you have a username and password based authentication only and developed custom forms anyway, it strikes me as the wrong approach to use Keycloak here if you don't intend to work with the tokens provided by it. Normally, the password shouldn't be used to authenticate a user, the cookie or JWT should be used.

@maio290 Thanks for your reply. I am in the keycloak side, I modified keycloak login page with mobile number and OTP.  client applications are using that. But now I need to add username and password form as well in some situations. So now need to modify the backend code.

What if the user is logged in via a social provider?  Keycloak doesn't have the credentials for that, just a token.

Here is the solution worked for me. I used validatePassword function in the AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator class.
My inputData from form parameter provide username and password.
private UserModel getUserByUserNameAndPassword(AuthenticationFlowContext context, String username) {
    RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();
    UserModel user = context.getSession().users().getUserByUsername(realm, username);
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> inputData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
    boolean shouldClearUserFromCtxAfterBadPassword = !isUserAlreadySetBeforeUsernamePasswordAuth(context);

    if (user != null
            && validatePassword(context, user, inputData, shouldClearUserFromCtxAfterBadPassword)) {
        return user;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


The main issue you're probably facing on your way to implement is that you're trying to compare a plaintext password with a hashed and salted password.
Given that one of their integration tests looks like that:  [Source]:
  UserProvider userProvider = session.getProvider(UserProvider.class);
  UserModel user = userProvider.getUserByUsername(userName, realm);
  return userProvider.validCredentials(session, realm, user, UserCredentialModel.password(password));

You should be able to do the following:
UserProvider userProvider = context.getSession().getProvider(UserProvider.class);
UserModel user = userProvider.getUserByUsername(userName, context.getRealm());
final booolean isValidPassword = userProvider.validCredentials(context.getSession(), context.getRealm(), user, UserCredentialModel.password(password));


Thank you @mario290 , But the validCredentials function seems to be not available in UserProvider. Getting an error like "The method validCredentials(KeycloakSession, RealmModel, UserModel, PasswordUserCredentialModel) is undefined for the type UserProvider".
But UserCredentialModel.password(password) might help me. I will debug with this.

@Prifulnath In case of doubt just search their GIT repository for the methods. Just tried to help. Hope you'll achieve what you're trying to implement, good luck! :)

here is my solution. I used credentialManager() method on UserModel.
UserProvider userProvider = context.getSession().getProvider(UserProvider.class);
UserModel user = userProvider.getUserByUsername(context.getRealm(), username);

boolean isPasswordValid = user.credentialManager().isValid(UserCredentialModel.password(password))

